# Change HTML Class content using VBA

Tags: html, class

Is it possible to use Excel VBA to change the content of this class `Class="wix-list-item section is-section-hoverable"` to this `Class="wix-list-item section is-section-hoverable is-section-hidden"`, using Excel VBA code with Internet Explorer?

[image: Screenshot HTML]

This is to update my E-commerce stock, another code will check my supliers stock and if it returns 0, it will change that so it wont be available in my store.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please can you add some details to your question? Do you have an excel sheet with an embedded browser control? I'm no `VBA` expert, but you'll have either have to walk the `dom` of the browser or you probably can use `xpath` - as an example this [blog post](http://www.aswinvanwoudenberg.com/2009/04/02/web-scraping-using-xpath-and-visual-basic/) explains it,

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of code. Instead, [edit] and copy-paste your code in the question, select it and press CTRL+K or the `{}` button to format it.